# Trying to print with String.join but it does not work

Tags: java, string

I am trying to print these keys from the code below. When I use String.join it doesn't print them separated by comma and space but as one word. Not sure what am I doing wrong.

```
String[] words = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase().split(" ");

LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> count = new LinkedHashMap<>();


for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

    Integer occurrences = count.get(words[i]);
    if (occurrences == null) {
        occurrences = 0;
    }
    count.put(words[i], occurrences + 1);
}
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : count.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.print(String.join(", ", entry.getKey()));
    }
}
```

}
}

Comment: `enty.getKey()` returns a single `String`. If you consider a `join(a, b)` function, and pass only `a` you get only `a`. What behavior did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> *     String message = String.join("-", "Java", "is", "cool");
> *     // message returned is: "Java-is-cool"
> ```

Above is quoted from the Java doc of `String.join` method. The first argument is the 'delimiter'. Since `entry.getKey()` returns just a single string, there's no use adding you delimiter 'comma' there. That's the expected behavior.

May be `StringJoiner` will be more of a choice here.

Answer (score 0):

The `String.join` method in your code is executed for each word individually. You need to collect all the words first (for example inside a `ArrayList`) and then do the execute `Strin.join(", ", <your list object>)` afterwards.